# VBA to log-in to webpage (determine if needed)

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm trying to put a section at the beginning of my sub in order to do 2 things.
1. determine if I need to login.
2. enter login information.

The URL is the same whether its the login page or the loggedin page.
I noticed that On the login page theres a login box element but no search box. On the logged in page its vice versa.
Noting this, I tried to set an If command that If i don't see the search box, to enter log-in information.

```
Dim myElem as variant
Set myElem = IE.document.getElementById("ctl05_TextBoxSCN")
If (myElem = Null) Then
IE.document.getElementById("txtUsername").Value = Range("h1")
IE.document.getElementById("txtPassword").Value = Range("J1")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
SendKeys "{Enter}", True
End If
```

but I keep getting an error saying: object variable or with block variable not set

note: that cells h1 is my username and J1 my password. and CT105_TextBoxSCN is the id for textbox shown if i'm loggedin.

Comment: Which line of code do you get the error on?

Comment: Try `If myElem Is Nothing`

Comment: myElem Is Nothing returns an error: Invalid use of object

Comment: My error is on the line with myElem = Null
Since trying to test myElem = nothing changed the error message and I know from previous testing that the the lines below it will work. If i made it to the lines below it I would have seen the webpage textbox display my h1 cell value on the webpage.

Comment: `Dim myElem as Object`

Comment: I changed Dim myElem as variant to Dim myElem as Object in my original posted sub. Same error: Object variable not set

Comment: Is my Set myElem =   line correct? is this a viable way to see if that element exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Dim myElem as Object
Set myElem = IE.document.getElementById("ctl05_TextBoxSCN")
If myElem Is Nothing Then
    'element not found
Else
    'element found
End If
```

Comment: Dude! You're the man! I thought I had it typed in this way after your myelem is nothing suggestion but must've mistyped anything. That works! thank you