# VBA - Skip Login Page if site is already logged in IE

Tags: excel, vba

I am new on StackOverflow and actually searched for this topic and cannot find anything yet.

If IE opens for the first time with code then there is no problem with my code site asks login credentials and my macro fills it. however in case of web site is already opened and logged in the system, my macro craches. that is why I want to skip this stage if known ID is not in the webpage.

I have seen a solution on this website but it did not work for me. here is the link.

[VBA to log-in to webpage (determine if needed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183988/vba-to-log-in-to-webpage-determine-if-needed/59144413#59144413)

and also code on link is as below.

```
Dim myElem as Object
Set myElem = IE.document.getElementById("ctl05_TextBoxSCN")
If myElem Is Nothing Then
    'element not found
Else
    'element found
End If
```

I am taking object required error for Set myElem = ie.document.getElementById("xxx") section. and site is not loging in. but if site is already logged in macro works properly.

if I clear above steps macro works properly for just new ie page at this time and cruches for if logged in another ie page. thanks for your help

```
Public Sub MakeSelection()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://sample.com"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
Dim myElem As Object
Set myElem = ie.document.getElementById("xxx")
If myElem Is Nothing Then
  With .document
  .getElementById("UserName").Focus
  .getElementById("UserName").Value = Sheets("LoginData").Range("B1").Text
  .getElementById("Password").Focus
  .getElementById("Password").Value = Sheets("LoginData").Range("B2").Text
  .getElementById("LoginButton").Click
  End With

  Else
```

Comment: Is `IE` declared and assigned anywhere? You'd get "object required" if `IE` wasn't declared or assigned.

Comment: I have already  assigned it `Dim ie As New InternetExplorer`

Comment: We cannot guess that from the code you posted. Please [edit] your question to include enough code to reliably reproduce the problem, see [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for editing. You're inside a `With ie` block - you want `Set myElem = .document......`

Comment: yeah seen it after amendmend still getting same error. is there any other way to skip it ?

Comment: Does it say `Option Explicit` at the top of your module? If not, make it so. Does your code still compile with it? This isn't an error you can just shove under the carpet - something is syntactically wrong.

Comment: `Option Explicit` added to module and still getting same error. I think I need to recheck with fresh mind at the morning.

Comment: `Option Explicit` should always be there, it validates that all identifiers are properly declared, which rules out the `.document` member call ever happening against a `Variant/Empty` ad-hoc undeclared runtime variable, which would cause the error you're getting. Verify what the output of `TypeName(ie.document.getElementById("xxx"))` is - it it's `Variant()`, then remove the `Set` and declare the `Elem` variable `As Variant`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added if to lookup a word in page that opens after login pages, checking the site is already opened or still asking password and username.

here is the code.

```
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    Dim myElem As Variant
        ie.Visible = True
        ie.navigate "https://test.htm"
        While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
'newpage a word exist inside first page after password
        myElem = ie.document.getElementById("newpage")
        If IsNull(ie.document.getElementById("newpage")) Then
            ie.document.getElementById("UserName").Focus
            ie.document.getElementById("UserName").Value = Sheets("LoginData").Range("B1").Text
            ie.document.getElementById("Password").Focus
            ie.document.getElementById("Password").Value = Sheets("LoginData").Range("B2").Text
            ie.document.getElementById("LoginButton").Click
            End If
```